# Push multistage image to dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I'm trying to use multistage in a Dockerfile to build an app (buildstage) and execute it.
Everything works fine.
But once i want to push my image on docker, the onlypart that is pushed is the one about running my app.

Is there anyway to push both stage in one image?

My dockerfile is like following :

```
# Fetch and build example
FROM alpine:latest AS buildstage
LABEL stage=builder
RUN echo "buildstage"
ENV REFRESHED_AT 2020-27-04
# --no-cache to reduce size
# use apk add build-base?
RUN apk --no-cache add alpine-sdk
WORKDIR /home/myuser
RUN git clone https://.../myproject.git
RUN cd myproject&& . ./environment-x86 && make clean && make

# Exec example
FROM alpine:latest as execexample
RUN echo "execexample"
WORKDIR /home/myuser
COPY --from=buildstage /home/myuser/myproject/out/x86/helloworld.exe .
CMD ["./helloworld.exe"]
```

All I see on the digest of Docker Hub is :

```
1 ADD file ... in /
2 CMD ["/bin/sh"]
3 /bin/sh -c echo "execexample"
4 WORKDIR /home/myuser
5 COPY file:078e4c246713e8ff749cb427c41d539173308016398e762e10b47ce543e0f062 in .
6 CMD ["./helloworld.exe"]
```

How can the first part added to docker hub?

Comment: That is how multi stage builds work.

Comment: So this meens that if I want all the process, multi stage is not what I have to use?

Comment: Probably not.  What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: It's mostly a demo/personal training. Aim was to built a projet hosted on a git server (which is ok) and executing the binary in order to test the code (which is ok too). I thought about using docker hub to "save" the global image but considering the result, I should save the dockerfile and built the solution when I want to use it. So if I need to rebuilt it, I may use something different than "alpine-sdk" in order to save few seconds on the build step.

Comment: You are using a two step file for building and deploying.  If this was for a real use scenario this would be _exactly_ what you would want for an image published for others.  If you think building is too slow, then consider why.

Comment: Ok, so Docker Hub is about storing image used by final user. Thanks for those advices.

Comment: Well, Docker Hub is for storing images for use by _others_.  What those images will then be actually used for, is not a concern of Docker Hub.  You could rework your current build into two images which both could be put on DockerHub, but for what purpose?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. Thanks.